# How should we deal with questions that border on illegal activity (ID Fraud)

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, questions

So with [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35816/remove-a-picture-from-id-without-affecting-those-yellow-lines) question being the example I wonder how we should deal with it?

The OP may well have entirely innocent intentions with their purpose for changing details and images on an I.D but another person in future may not have such innocent intentions and our answers would then aid them in ID fraud.

I'm not sure if I'm reading too much into the morals/legislation surrounding the question that in essence is merely a graphical one.

Should we be concerned about what we may be facilitating for in answering a question like this?

Does a question like this compromise the reputation of the site?

Comment: The line is blurry is some cases like here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35793/serif-font-identification

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the response was quick and effective. Downvote and close. The technique requested might be ok by itself, but tampering with IDs is illegal, everywhere. I don't think we have a 'rule' about this, it would simply be **wrong** to promote / allow for this to be accessible. I'm quite content with this reason alone :)

Comment: Agreed - that is the absurd thing about that question. If it had not been an ID, but a similar problem, the OP would have gotten good answers. Not very tactical.

Comment: Yeah it was a bit much! Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 6):

Anything along these lines should be flagged for a moderator to review.  I believe if the question regards a manner or be considered we will close it because that is not the intentions of the site to condone illegal manners..  if the question didnt show someone's id with personal info it would be treated differently.

The rule I use is if its personal info or something you don't want on the site dont put it out there.  If its something you see as personal then flag it.

A side note to that.  If you post your personal designs for a critique we will not remove it if it receives answers because that makes the question useless to someone else in the future

Comment: I took it a step further and deleted the question, but for future reference replacing the picture with "_IMAGE REMOVED BECAUSE IT DISPLAYED PERSONAL INFO._" will just fuel people's curiosity to check the edit history and take a look at the personal info that was removed

Comment: Agreed but doesnt the link to the question she have above need to be edited

Comment: I totally checked the edit history out of curiosity after reading "IMAGE REMOVED..." :S sounds like I'm part of the problem...

Comment: Wish I could mark both as right...err should I do something with that link? :)